# Dynamically adding drop down lists inside gridview cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a grid view, if the database is returning null for a particular column I want to insert a drop down list that is populated from a database.

Here is the code I have to identify the the column is null and it is working correctly.

```
protected void viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "&nbsp;")
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
         //fill current rows cell with a dropdown list
     }
}
```

Here is the gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" OnRowDataBound="viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView_OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" >
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Additionally, once I populate the row, how do I know which drop down list specifically is being used when there are many versions of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Design   
 <asp:GridView ID="viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
            CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" 
            OnRowDataBound="viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView_RowDataBound" 
            DataSourceID="Sql_New" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="New Column" >
                <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlnew" runat ="server" Visible ="false" ></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sql_New" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EmployeeConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblnew]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


Code
protected void viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "&nbsp;")
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList ddlnew = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlnew");
                ddlnew.Visible = true;
            }
        }

    }
```